# Add audio to ImageSwitcher

Tags: android, imageswitcher

My first post.

Can I add short audio and text to ImageSwitcher that will change according to the image. I would like to add a textview and audio at the bottom that will change at the same time as images on the top.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 methods to play sounds on certain events:
[MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) and [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html).

The simplest way to do what you want is:

```
//loading the sound "MY_SOUND_EFFECT" from the "res/raw" folder  
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.MY_SOUND_EFFECT);

//playing the sound (this line goes into your event handler block)  
mp.start();
```

Comment: Thank You. I am familiar with that. I have this layout Gallery at the top and imageView in the middle. I would like to add audio at to the name of image at the same time as I change the image                                 <Gallery android:id="@+id/galleryView" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical"/>                             <ImageSwitcher android:id="@+id/windows" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/galleryView"
android:paddingTop="40dp"> </ImageSwitcher>

Answer (score -1):

```
imgswitch.setImageResource(images[0]);
    if(i==0) {prev.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    suara_hewan=MediaPlayer.create(hewan_darat.this,
    suara[0]);
    suara_hewan.start();}

    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (i < images.length - 1) {
                i++;
                if (i == images.length - 1) {
                    next.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                } else {
                    prev.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                suara_hewan = MediaPlayer.create(hewan_darat.this,
                                suara[i]);
                suara_hewan.setVolume(2,5);
                suara_hewan.start();
                imgswitch.setImageResource(images[i]);
            }
        }
    });

    prev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (i > 0) {
                i--;
                if (i == 0) {
                    prev.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                } else {
                    next.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                suara_hewan = MediaPlayer.create(hewan_darat.this,
                        suara[i]);
                suara_hewan.setVolume(2,5);
                suara_hewan.start();
                imgswitch.setImageResource(images[i]);
            }
```